# ListView overlaps elements when at top of list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting an odd, visual glitch when using a ListView in my Flutter app. I've reproduced the issue in a minimal piece of code (below).

When the list is scrolled to the top, the list overlaps the elements beneath it. As soon as I scroll down a little, the list respects the boundaries of the `Expanded` element it sits within and the overlapping stops.

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

Above, the left image shows the flaw. Note how the elements are overlapping the red area. The right image shows the situation once I've scrolled a little, now we can see the correct space appearing above the red area.

Have I done something wrong or is there a bug here?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleWidget()));
}

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new AspectRatio(
          child: new Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("a"))),
              new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("b"))),
              new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("c"))),
              new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("d"))),
              new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("e"))),
            ],
          ),
          flex: 10,
        ),
        new Expanded(child: new Container(), flex: 3),

        new Container(
          height: 60.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),

        new Expanded(child: new Container(), flex: 2),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The issue occurs when I run the app on my phone as well.

`Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-GB)`

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Can you reproduce in `beta` channel?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added my version info to the question.

Comment: Your issue somehow looks similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17716. My example worked fine with the previous beta (0.3.2 if I remember correctly) or the commit before the one `git bisect` found (see comments in the linked issue)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the link, it certainly looks related. For now, I'll post as an issue on GitHub and keep working. (I'm assuming my code is ok and this is a glitch).

Comment: Issue posted here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17880

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this bug today -  I was on the beta branch, but switching to master and rebuilding did not solve the issue.  It seems that when the ListView position is at 0 offset with respect to the top, i.e. when the "no more scroll" animation would appear on Android (as opposed to spring action on iOS), the Tiles will overflow the ListView's container for whatever reason.  Hope they patch it soon!  I've tried wrapping it in Flex containers and fitted boxes, covering the overflow with layers, etc., none of it works. Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: I ran into this issue today and it got fixed by following the recommendation here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17880#issuecomment-402835644

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleWidget()));
}

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(child: new Container(),),
          new Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("a"))),
                      new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("b"))),
                      new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("c"))),
                      new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("d"))),
                      new Card(child: new ListTile(title: new Text("e"))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to have a 1:1 aspect ratio area that will always fill the screen width. Since I'm using a lot of flexible space, I struggled to ensure the area would always fill the width. Hence I settled on fixing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` as the height. Any suggestions for how to do this in other ways?

Comment: Do you actually need empty space between the list and bottom container or it's a part of glitch?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Have a look at it. If you need empty space between list and container add an Expanded widget and adjust flex accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, however I don't understand your edit - you've removed the aspect ratio widget that I need.

Comment: You don't need aspect ratio widget for your requirement. You can split the screen into two parts by simply using two Expanded widgets.

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions if any. Because I'm also a beginner to flutter and I can also gain some knowledge by answering.

Comment: I need exactly a 1:1 ratio for that component, so it is required. Anyway, I’ll see if I can achieve what I want without the MediaQuery, once I’ve tested if that’s the issue. Thanks for the pointer. I’ll report back.